# Iterating through two objects with different structures in parallel

Tags: javascript, array, iteration

I have two objects, one `input = Array<Type>` and one `stored = Array<{..., Type}>`

What's the best (cleanest) way to put the elements in the first array into the sub-elements of the second? We can assume they're of the same size.

My current code below works, but looks bad due to the double iterator usage.

```
var count = 0;
stored.forEach((obj)=> {
    obj.value = input[count];
    count++;
});
```

Is there some sort of prototyping that I can use to shorten the code up?

Comment: don't know if this qualifies as an answer but you don't need the `count` variable to increment the index, `Array.forEach` accepts a second ( optional ) parameter which is the current index that you can use : `stored.forEach((obj, ndx) => { obj.value = input[ndx]; });` https://jsfiddle.net/qm6yep5r/

Comment: @Taki That's exactly it. Thanks a lot! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the count variable to increment the index, [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) accepts a second ( optional ) parameter which is the current index that you can use :

```
stored.forEach((obj, index) => { 
   obj.value = input[index]; 
});
```

OR

```
stored = stored.map((obj, index) => ({...obj, value: input[index]}))
```

example :

```js
let stored = [{ name : 'a', value: 2 }, {name : 'b',  value: 4 }, { name : 'c',  value: 6 }];
let input = [10, 11, 12];


stored.forEach((obj, index) => { obj.value = input[index]; });

// OR
// stored = stored.map((obj, index) => ({...obj, value: input[index]}))

console.log(stored)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the existing answer pointed out there is a index argument passed to the array iteration callbacks `callback(item, idx, array)`

### Iterators

However you could also use an iterator

`[Array.values()][1]` returns an array iterator. You use `iterator.next()` to step over the items, and `iterator.next().value` to get an item.

That way you do not need an index and can use the more performant `for of` loop that does not have a ready idx.

```
const iterator = input.values();
for (const obj of stored) { obj.value = iterator.next().value }
```

However is works equally well in an array iteration function

```
const iterator = input.values();
stored.forEach(obj => obj.value = iterator.next().value)
```

### Via a generator

You can also create a custom iterator using a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*). For example say you wanted to reverse the input order.

```
function *reversed(array) { // NOTE the * signifies this is a generator 
    var i = array.length;
    while (i--) { yield array[i] }
}

var iterator = reversed(input); // create reverse iterator of input
for (const obj of stored) { obj.value = iterator.next().value }

// or

iterator = reversed(input); // restart reverse iterator of input
stored.forEach(obj => obj.value = iterator.next().value);
```

Note that the iteration assigning to `store` remained unchanged from above examples.